# Using css grid with preloader and dynamic html

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hi my html initially looks like this:

```
<app>
    <div id="preloader">
    </div>
</app>
```

but after app loads it's being replaced with

```
<app>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <div id="other">
    </div>
</app>
```

But how do I actually have to setup css-grid for this to make `preloader` full screen, but `main` and `other` templated?

**Page does not reload**

I'd kind of want to use them both at once

```
grid-template-areas: 
"preloader";

grid-template-areas: 
"main other"
"main other"
"main other";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply make the loader to span all the grid that is defined for your main content:

```css
app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "main other" 
    "main other" 
    "main other";
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: red;
}

#other {
  grid-area: other;
  background: green;
}

#preloader {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
While loading
<app>
  <div id="preloader">
  </div>
</app>
After content is loaded
<app>
  <div id="main">
  </div>
  <div id="other">
  </div>
</app>
```